# R how to reference a dynamically created object

Tags: r

I have the following R code which creates 5 objects dynamically with names such as cluster1_dataset, ...., cluster5_dataset as follows:

```
# Extract cluster data
for (i in 1:K) {
  assign(paste("cluster",i,"_dataset",sep=""), subset(clustered_input_dataset, cluster == i))
}
```

How do i access these 5 dynamically created objects in R?

I have tried the following:

```
# Plot histograms & boxplots for each cluster to look at shift_length_avg   frequency distribution
par(mfrow=c(K,2))
for (i in 1:K) {
# Analyze cluster#1
  hist(dataset$shift_length_avg)
}
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Error in dataset$shift_length_avg : 
 $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: You really should not have to use `assign()` and `paste()` if you are new to R. That's usually a sign you are not doing things in the R-like way. you probably should have named lists which you can easily index via `[[ ]]`

Comment: Put the subsets in a list: `K.list <- lapply(1:K, function(i) subset(clustered_input_dataset, cluster==i))`. Eventuall you are looking for `split()`. `K.list <- split(clustered_input_dataset, clustered_input_dataset$cluster)`

Comment: Or even use lapply and split: 'lapply(split(clustered_input_dataset$shift_length_avg, clustered_input_dataset$cluster), hist)`

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17499013/903061) for more tips on using lists of data frames.

Answer (score 1):

The `assign()` function has a twin called `get()`. This is the function that you need.
Refer to this concise and easy-to-understand article [here](https://www.rpubs.com/stenevang/about_assign_and_get).